# Python nested function variable scope:dictionary vs integer? (Leetcode 662 DFS Solution)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at the DFS solution of Leetcode 662 (https://leetcode.com/articles/maximum-width-of-binary-tree/) and got confused about the variable scoping in nested functions. The `max_width` variable has to be decaled nonlocal, but the dictionary `first_col_index_table` does not and can be directly used in the nested function. Could someone help me with this variable scope problem? Really appreciate it!

```
class Solution:
    def widthOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:

        # table contains the first col_index for each level
        first_col_index_table = {}
        max_width = 0

        def DFS(node, depth, col_index):
            nonlocal max_width
            if node is None:
                return
            # if the entry is empty, set the value
            if depth not in first_col_index_table:
                first_col_index_table[depth] = col_index

            max_width = max(max_width, col_index - first_col_index_table[depth] + 1)

            # Preorder DFS, with the priority on the left child
            DFS(node.left, depth+1, 2*col_index)
            DFS(node.right, depth+1, 2*col_index + 1)

        DFS(root, 0, 0)

        return max_width
```

Comment: You need the `nonlocal` declaration because `max_width` would otherwise be a local variable - due to the assignment to it in the inner function.  But you aren't assigning anything to `first_col_index_table`, you are merely mutating it - an option that does not exist with integers.

Comment: Thank you Jason, this solves my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

### [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

> ```
> nonlocal_stmt ::=  "nonlocal" identifier ("," identifier)*
> ```
>
> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
> previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding
> globals. This is important because the default behavior for binding is
> to search the local namespace first. The statement allows encapsulated
> code to rebind variables outside of the local scope besides the global
> (module) scope.
>
> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global
> statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope
> (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be
> determined unambiguously).
>
> Names listed in a nonlocal statement must not collide with
> pre-existing bindings in the local scope.

You can also solve the problem iteratively. This'd pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def widthOfBinaryTree(self, root):
        queue = [(root, 0, 0)]
        curr_depth = 0 
        left = 0 
        max_width = 0
        for node, depth, pos in queue:
            if node:
                queue.append((node.left, depth + 1, pos * 2))
                queue.append((node.right, depth + 1, pos * 2 + 1))
                
                if curr_depth != depth:
                    curr_depth = depth
                    left = pos
                max_width = max(max_width, pos - left + 1)
        return max_width
```

Or use `self`:

```
class Solution:
    def widthOfBinaryTree(self, root):

        # table contains the first col_index for each level
        first_col_index_table = {}
        self.max_width = 0

        def DFS(node, depth, col_index):
            if node is None:
                return
            # if the entry is empty, set the value
            if depth not in first_col_index_table:
                first_col_index_table[depth] = col_index

            self.max_width = max(self.max_width, col_index - first_col_index_table[depth] + 1)

            # Preorder DFS, with the priority on the left child
            DFS(node.left, depth+1, 2*col_index)
            DFS(node.right, depth+1, 2*col_index + 1)

        DFS(root, 0, 0)

        return self.max_width
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-width-of-binary-tree/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.